# error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'b_arr'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boolean, using

```
using b_arr = bool [10];
```

i have written this code in code::blocks on windows. i have seen many other posts on the same error but do not understand what is wrong in my code.

i actually want to use the resulting user-defined data type for a function to return a boolean array created inside the function. i also do not understand how i will do that(return a boolean array). please help.

i am a novice in programming and coding, so it would be nice have some explanations

Comment: Go to your project options, and make sure the C++ language standard you are using is C++11 or higher.

Comment: What flags have you enabled or used when building the code? Do you have enabled C++11 (which is where type-aliasing with `using` was introduced)?

Comment: Besides that issue, how are you intending to use the type alias? Because with the type `bool[]` you can't define normal variables, since the size is unknown.

Comment: please tell me where to find the option to check c++11 in code::blocks 16.01.